# Teamcity Git VCS root deletes .git folder

Tags: git, teamcity

We are using TeamCity Enterprise 2017.2.2 and when I was triggering a build today on one of the .net project (It was working fine before we upgraded to this version), and running the following metarunner:

```
git fetch origin --tags gitversion /nofetch /output buildserver /UpdateAssemblyInfo
```

throws me an error:

```
Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

When I look at the workdir, it has all the files and folders except .git folder.
So looks like, Git vcs root worked initially fine to bring down contents of my project and then it deleted .git folder.

When I clone same repo into my local environment, it work just fine. I can do all git operations within. That means, there is no problem with the project Git repo itself

Can someone please suggest how can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: what are your permission on the .git directory itself?

Comment: TeamCity and buildagent are running under service account and that account is currently setup as a part of local admin group. So it has full permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem. On VCS page, there is an option for VCS checkout mode. It was initially set to "Always checkout files on server". I changed it to "Always checkout files on Agent" and it seems to be working now.

Answer (score -1):

I know this may be weird, but have you cd into the actual directory that has been cloned down. You will not be able to access git remotely unless you are in a folder with a git environment. -if you then do a git status after this command, you may find that you can read from that source now.

Comment: Yes, I have a physical access to the server and I am looking directly into that WorkDir folder.

Comment: Try git init then

Comment: Will not it initialize the local git repository?

Comment: Yes that will initialize it

Comment: But then, one of our steps commits some files back to remote git repo after build succeeds. Fir e.g. AssembyInfo.cs and few others. If it initializes only local git repo, its head is not pointing to the remote git repo.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init

it also re-initializes an 'already existing' repo